# Get words that are separated by various number of spaces with regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to grab each word in the string that can be separated by various number of whitespaces.

```
my $ff = "Disk  DSM     Policy  Paths   Serials";

if($ff =~ m/(\w+)/) {
    print $1;
    print $2;
    print $3;
}
```

I thought it would be as simple as \w but it only gets the first word? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [match `g`lobally](http://p3rl.org/retut#Global-matching).

```
my $ff = "Disk  DSM     Policy  Paths   Serials";

my (@words_match) = $ff =~ /(\w+)/g;
# (
#     'Disk',
#     'DSM',
#     'Policy',
#     'Paths',
#     'Serials'
# )
```

A better solution is to [split](http://p3rl.org/split).

```
my @words_split = split ' ', $ff;
# (
#     'Disk',
#     'DSM',
#     'Policy',
#     'Paths',
#     'Serials'
# )
```